# "Соседний" с предлогами

Tags: грамотная-речь

1. Насколько я знаю, выражение "**соседний с**" вполне употребимо. "**Соседняя с** гостиной комната называлась диванной." (Писемский, Боярщина). Правильно ли говорить "**соседний от**"? Пример: "Он садился за **соседний от** покинутого мною столик" (Марина Серова, Ядовитая паутина).
2. Правильно ли говорить "**соседний с кем-то**" вместо "**соседний с чьим-то**"? Примеры: "я сел за **соседний с ними** стол" (Дарья Калинина); "Я занимаю **соседний с Вами** номер"; "**соседний с Наташей** стол" (найдено в интернете). А если неправильно, то не могли бы вы предложить корректные аналоги? Мне кажется, надо говорить "соседний с Вашим номер", "соседний с Наташиным стол". А вот как быть, если имя не склоняется (например: "соседний с Шэрон Стоун номер")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких случаях, по-моему, следует идти от происхождения и смысла слова.
Сосед - буквально, СО (рядом, совместно) + СЕД (сидящий, находящийся). Поэтому, "соседний (находящийся рядом) от..." - звучит бессмысленно. Кроме того, слово соседний можно заменить имеющим тот же смысл "по соседству". Тогда "по соседству от..." - тоже неверно. Тут оказывает влияние близкое по смыслу выражение "недалеко от...". И ещё, просто подставьте в выражение любое слово с приставкой СО-. Ведь не говорят: содружественный от..., или совместный от..., или сопряженный от... . Соседний с нами или с нашим - правильно всё (в зависимости от контекста), так как можно иметь ввиду и "столик, находящийся рядом с нашим столиком", так и столик, находящийся рядом с нами (мы в этом случае можем вообще сидеть как за столом, так и на полу, и "наш столик" тут вообще не при чем, так как его просто нет). Сравните. 1. Мы стояли в очереди. За соседним с нами столиком... и 2. У нас (за нашим столиком) мест не было. Александр сел за соседний с нашим стол.

Answer (score 1):

Обратимся к словарю:

> СОСЕ́ДНИЙ, -яя, -ее. Расположенный по соседству, вблизи, рядом **с чем-л.** С-ее село. С-яя с гостиной комната была спальней. С-ие страны.

Так, *соседним* может быть что (или кто) угодно, расположенное вблизи с чем-то (кем-то). Например: *Мой почтовый ящик **соседний с её*** или *Александр сел за **соседний с нами** стол*.

Кажется, *Соседний с Наташей стол* звучит корректней, хотя и *Соседний с Наташиным (столом) стол* возможен.

Вы сами правильно сказали, что имя не склоняется - так не склоняйте его: *Вася жил в соседнем с Шэрон Стоун номере*.

Comment: "Соседний с Наташей стол"  звучит корректнее, только если Наташа присутствует. Если Наташи нет, но стол определённо её, лучше употреблять "соседний с Наташиным стол".

Comment: @Mae закручиваете слишком))

Comment: @Aer, а что по поводу "соседний от" скажете?

Comment: @М_Г В целом то же, однако, кажется, это стилистически окрашенный вариант.